# How can I reduce the space between two elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the simple form and attached the css file for that. As you can see there are 2 fields and one checkbox - I would like to make the checkbox directly under the textarea, with around 1-2px space, not as it is now - how can I modify that? I thought the problem is somewhere here:

```
.textox, .textoxarea {
    width: 340px;
    border: solid 1px #999999;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #9C9C9C;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    color: #474747;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

but I can't find the proper way of doing that.
Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hq0x6u4/1/).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the empty paragraphs between `textarea` and `checkbox`.

In your fiddle it's on lines 11 and 13.

http://jsfiddle.net/7hq0x6u4/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
.center p:nth-of-type(2),.center p:nth-of-type(3){
         margin:0;
}
```

This will reduce the space of margin in both the `P` tags which are covering the input elements

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7hq0x6u4/1/)

> Normally use of `p` tags to align input tags are not recommended.

Comment: hey, thanks, forgive my curiosity, but why using `p` is not recommended?

Comment: as you know `p` tag is meant to have text inside it and it acts as a text container and text based styling tags not a container for tags like input tags,etx so try to use div tags instead of p tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to your `<input type="checkbox">` add these styles.

```
 .foo {
    bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative; 
  }
```

**.foo** as an example class on checkbox.

Comment: Where is `.foo` in the fiddle?

Comment: I have written foo as an example class.

Comment: I see you are quite new in SO, in future please the proper selector, while the fiddle is attached to question. The other thing is that your solution doesn't work - it does almost nothing. Maybe you just misunderstood the question.